# Need to Reinstall, Have Activated Windows 7 on my PC, But lost the CD and Serial number

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reinstall Windows 7 if I lost my installation DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd)

Edit: The answer was to find the Serial number first using a serial number finder utility. The possible duplicate was missing the additional condition that the serial number was missing.

I have Activated Windows 7 on my PC, But lost the CD and Serial number.
I need to reinstall Windows 7, I (hope) can borrow a Windows 7 DVD somehow, but how do I get my original serial number, I have the product key as shown in System Properties.

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: You'd just need the product key to install it again. i don't see anything else on my win7 OEM package

Comment: In addition to the duplicate indicated above, you'll find the following questions useful: [Product key finders for Windows](http://superuser.com/q/176306/20088) and [Windows Activation FAQ](http://superuser.com/q/303136/20088). You should be able to recover your old product key, download a Windows disk image, and reinstall it yourself. You can also [back up your Windows activation files before you reinstall](http://superuser.com/q/190102/20088), and skip activation altogether.

Comment: You didn't write the numbers down on a gummed label and stick it on the bottom of your box?

Comment: @DanH : Nop, I didn't think the DVD will disappear.

Comment: If you don't have the COA sticker (the sticker product key and hologram on it), then you are running your copy of Windows illegally - irrespective of whether you've purchased it or not - if you lose the sticker, you lose you right to use the software. Furthermore if you are using an OEM version, the sticker must be attached to the PC it was supplied with. In short, using a product key finder might get you up and running, but that doesn't mean you have a legal copy of the operating system.

Comment: @nhinkle : Thank you for your suggestion regarding backing up of the activation files, +1

Comment: @Arjang sure thing. Good luck with your reinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Product Key Finder](http://davehope.co.uk/projects/product-key-finder/) from Dave Hope is quite good at finding what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install this http://www.freewarefiles.com/LicenseCrawler_program_44343.html

The program will list all your serial number in your computer including windows serial.

Another way to do is, if you bought the windows yourself and still have proof of purchase then you can call up microsoft and ask for serial.

Answer (score 1):

Download and run produkey http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html

Once you have the key you should be able to borrow a DVD however if it doesn't work try to get a DVD from the same manufacturer. If you bought it from off a self you will need a DVD also bought off the shelf.