# Format PC without losing Windows 7 license

Tags: windows-7, formatting, license-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows activation with planned reinstall](https://superuser.com/questions/190102/windows-activation-with-planned-reinstall)

I have a windows 7 intallation that I got from MSDN. The thing is that I want to format my PC and reinstall windows 7.

At first I thought I just have to write the current key somewhere, reinstall windows 7 normally and then activate it with my old key, but a friend did this and on the last step the activation wouldn't work because it said that the key was in use.

What can I do?

Comment: License sticker is maybe back on your Laptop,or rear the Desktop computer.

Comment: The process you *thought*, was the correct one. Maybe your friend's Key was used by someone else.

Comment: The OP mentions MSDN so no sticker

Comment: Your through process is correct; if you have a valid key that won't activate just find the phone number via Microsoft support - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950929/

Comment: I suspect that your friend had reinstalled many times (for some value of many). If you're doing this for the first time you *should* be OK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may work just fine but if not, you simply need to call the Microsoft number the activation tool will give you and explain the format and reinstall.  Takes a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation under Windows XP, I would just go ahead and re-install from scratch using the original key. When activation fails, there is an option to activate over the phone. You call the number, tell them that this is a re-install on the same computer and the license is not in use anywhere else, and then they'll tell you 50-digit code. Put that code in and you're good to go.

I think this still applies to Windows 7, but I'm not sure, as I haven't had to do it (yet) myself on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Same with Windows 7 last time I encountered this.  As you mention, do it where you can hear that long number.

Comment: I'm 99% sure I talked to a computer a year or two ago when I last had to do this.